# how to enable progress of downloading file using JavaScript or angular?

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring-boot

when i'm trying to download a file entire file is getting downloaded at once not able to see progress

below is the expected output
[image: not able to see progress like in this image]

i tried below 2 approaches but didn't help

Approach 1

tried using file saver

```
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
```

Approach 2
using pure javascript

```
  downloadFileDirect(blob){
      var a = document.createElement('a');
    var bb = new Blob([blob], { type: 'text/plain' });
    a.download = 'Upload.xlsx';
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(bb);
    a.textContent = 'Download ready';
    a.click();    
  }
```

in both the approaches file is getting downloaded at once

in backend its springboot

Comment: You can follow this tutorial https://roytuts.com/download-file-from-server-using-angular/, but if the file already downloads and you don't see the progress, it's probably just a small file.

Answer (score -1):

It's the browser that handles the download progress not Angular.

Comment: Well, that is just stating the problem in the question: the browser *should* handle it but decided *not to*, for whatever reason, at least the 'Approach 2'.